# How can I use double dimentional array without using index?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I know I can use array mixed with pointer.
For example, if there is an array like 
 `char words[6]= "abcde" ;`
I can print a letter by `printf("%c\n", *(words+i));` (i is roll of index).

I wonder how can I call a letter when this array is double dimentioned
(without using array index but using pointer like above).

Double dimentioned array would look like 
`char words[5][5] = {"car", "boat", "ship", "truck", "plane");`

Comment: @EOF thanks for answering my question. I tried your code but I couldn't get a letter or word... only broken letters were printed. And I wonder why you used " / " in the code.

Comment: Sorry, that was a brainfart. Here: `*(*(words+i)+j)`. That should do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know, there are generally two ways to do this:

Approach 1:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char words[5][5] = {"car", "boat", "ship", "truck", "plane"};
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < sizeof words / sizeof *words; i++)
        for(j = 0; j < sizeof *words / sizeof **words; j++)
            printf("%d:\t%c\n", *((char *)words + i * sizeof(*words) + j), *((char *)words + i * sizeof(*words) + j));
}
```

Approach 2:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char words[5][5] = {"car", "boat", "ship", "truck", "plane"};
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < sizeof words; i++)
        printf("%d:\t%c\n", *((char *)words + i), *((char *)words + i));
}
```

Output:

```
99:     c
97:     a
114:    r
0:  
0:  
98:     b
111:    o
97:     a
116:    t
0:  
115:    s
104:    h
105:    i
112:    p
0:  
116:    t
114:    r
117:    u
99:     c
107:    k
112:    p
108:    l
97:     a
110:    n
101:    e
```

---

> I wonder is there a way to call whole word. I mean not using %c, but
>   %s. And also I want to fill words array with scanf. How should I do
>   it?

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char words[5][6];
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < sizeof words / sizeof *words; i++)
        fgets(words[i], sizeof words[i], stdin); // not using scanf() to avoid buffer overflow
    for(i = 0; i < sizeof words / sizeof *words; i++)
        puts(words[i]);
}
```

The type of `words[i]` is `char(*)[6]`, namely, an array of 6 `char`s.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I wonder is there a way to call whole word. I mean not using `%c`, but `%s`. And also I want to fill `words` array with `scanf`. How should I do it?

Comment: In fact, you need a ` words[5][6]` to hold five-letter words such as "truck", since there will be an terminating '\0'

Comment: Yes, I got that one. Thanks. Do you have an idea about comment question?